# ¿Como desplegar el menuContextual de un input type="datatime-local" con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un `<input id="miInput" type="datetime-local">` y necesito desplegar el calendario para selecionar una fecha pero oprimiendo un `<button id="miBoton"> Mi Boton </button>`. ¿que evento puedo utilizar para desplegar este menu contextual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede. No hay un API estandar ya que todos los navegadores lo implementan a su manera. Lo unico que puedes hacer es `focus` al elemento o utilizar algun [plugin de bootstrap](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Ejemplo focus:

```html
<input type="datetime-local">
  
 <button onclick="document.querySelector('input').focus()">abrir</button>
```